# How to insert a rails variable in to .js.erb span name?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I've got a .js.erb file that needs to replace a view's span based on the variable used in the associated controller.  I can't figure out the proper notation to get the call to work.  `@i` is assinged in the controller.  Here's the .js.erb call:

```
$("span#remove_name_" + <%= @i %>).html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'remove_position'))%>");
```

The name of the span I wish to replace is `remove_name_42` for example.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your `@i` is 42? Try: `alert("<%= @i %>");` to make sure.

Comment: I don't know where to place that code to test it.  The actions are completed in the background so I know that @i is the appropriate number at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just talk about this part of the code: `$("span#remove_name_" + <%= @i %>)`

You must understand how files with double extensions work. In this case you have a file of type ".js.erb" that means your file will be interpreted by erb first, and the result will be a js file that will be interpreted by the browser. The 2 interpretations are done separately.

About the erb interpretation: try to keep in mind that it's just some kind of 'text processing'. If you try to figure out step by step what's append:

1. Your code is `$("span#remove_name_" + <%= @i %>)`
2. The @i value is 'example'
3. erb replace this part of code `<%= @i %>` by the value if @i, which is 'example'
4. the resulting js file will be: `$("span#remove_name_" + example)`

If your js code declared a variable named 'example' and the resulting code `$("span#remove_name_" + example)` is what you was expecting, then it's good.

But if your js code do not declare a 'example' variable, and your are expecting this code `$("span#remove_name_example")` because you are searching the span with id "remove_name_example" then this is how it must be done:

1. Your code is `$("span#remove_name_<%= @i %>")`
2. The @i value is 'example'
3. erb replace this part of code `<%= @i %>` by the value if @i, which is 'example'
4. the resulting js file will be: `$("span#remove_name_example")`

See how we removes the `+` and moved `<%= @i %>` inside the string? Once again think about 'text processing' and keep in mind that erb replace a variable by its value.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this clearly.  It got me on my way to solving my problem.